# onBackPressed display Navigation Drawer Panel

Tags: android, android-fragments

I made a simple app which uses the Navigation Drawer and I just don't like the way that the back button works. If I open a fragment from the drawer and I press the back button it closes the app.I want that when I press the back button (no matter in which fragment I am ) to display the navigation panel ( just like in Zedge app ).

MainActivity:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Audi();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new BMW();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new Volkswagen();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Kia();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new Volvo();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the fragment to the backstack before you commit it, add this code before .commit() and try again;

```
.addToBackStack()
```